# Summernote always open link in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, summernote

When users are inserting a link with Summernote, it gives them the option of whether the link should open in a new tab or not. How can I force the user to always choose open a link in a new tab? Even just being able to hide that option would be useful becuase I could add in `target="_blank"` on the server side. Either way, I have been trying many things but I haven't been able to find an answer.

http://summernote.org/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with Summernote, there should be an option in the API to disable that but if you're looking for a quick solution, you can target the option through CSS and hide it.

**CSS hiding:**

```
.note-editor .link-dialog .checkbox { display: none; }
```

However I think it will remain the default state (unchecked), to force it to be checked you'll need JavaScript.

**Force check with JavaScript:**

```
document.querySelector('.note-editor .link-dialog .checkbox input').checked = true;
```

Comment: @ZachPanzarino can you create a jsfiddle or share a live demo for debugging?

Comment: I have been using a custom configuration of summernote and therefore the classes were not the same. I have been able to figure it out.

Comment: Is this the only way to go about this? Or is there a config setting for this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the summernote.js file and find

```
$openInNewWindow.prop('checked', linkInfo.isNewWindow);
```

Set this forcefully true by replacing the linkInfo.isNewWindow.

```
$openInNewWindow.prop('checked', true);
```

Hopefully it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `linkTargetBlank: false` option to disable default checked on the checkbox.

Like this:

```
$('.wysiwyg').summernote({
    linkTargetBlank: false
});
```

See the pull request on github: https://github.com/summernote/summernote/pull/2195

Comment: I had to add "// @ts-ignore" above the line "....summernote({..." to make typescript's type checking happy.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using Summernote **v0.8.11** just go to the summernote.js file and set `isNewWindow: true` to true instead of `$openInNewWindow.is(':checked')`. It's around line 6219.

```
$openInNewWindow.prop('checked', isNewWindowChecked);
$linkBtn.one('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  deferred.resolve({
      range: linkInfo.range,
      url: $linkUrl.val(),
      text: $linkText.val(),
      isNewWindow: $openInNewWindow.is(':checked') // change this
  });
  _this.ui.hideDialog(_this.$dialog);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the class .sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window with pointer events set to none. by default it is set to open in new window, so you just make the checkbox unclickable

```
.sn-checkbox-open-in-new-window{
   pointer-events:none !important
}
```